# RDP 'Incorrect Password' from 'Some Clients'

Tags: windows, vpn, remote-desktop

I'm RDP'ing to a customer site over a VPN. From my Mac running a Windows 10 virtual machine it works fine. My RDP username and password are accepted.

However, when I use two different Windows 10 desktop PC's, it tells me that the password I enter is incorrect. I'm 100% sure what I'm entering is correct.

Can I somehow get a bit more logging from RDP? Why is it working from one PC, but telling me the password is incorrect when RDPing from another?

The machine I am RDPing into is always the same. I've already asked the IT department, but they couldn't help.